# Reduce the AWS lambda node function size

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have used **serverless-webpack** npm module to reduce the size of my nodeJs serverless application but apparently the size is gtting increased from 15M to 85MB with usage of this packag and i am unable to deploy to lambda.

Do we have any other ways to reduce the size of node lambda function to ignore sending node_modules and improve the speed of th lambda function.

Comment: That module is supposed to bundle things so you don't need `node_modules` at all – how have you configured it? How are you deploying to Lambda?

Comment: 85MB is really big amount of code, so I suspect you have some binaries included in the package. Do you?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov there are no binaries involved in the application

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [esbuild-loader](https://github.com/privatenumber/esbuild-loader) for webpack, as it is more effective and provides really good tree-shaking (bundling only code which is really used  by your application rather than bundling everything).

As an alternative, you may use the corresponding serverless [plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-esbuild), but since you already have webpack configured it may be more convenient to use the first option.